# How to highlight an entire row using conditional formatting. With duplicates being tested

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am looking for a formula that highlights duplicate sequences but at the same time highlights the entire row. I am using this formula for the duplicates right now

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$24241, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4))) > 1
```

The way my data is presented goes something like column: A,B,C,D,E with around 25000 rows. What I want to do is highlight the duplicates but at the same time highlight the entire row of that duplicate.

[image: Example of row]

Example:

```
45| 120| 20|15

45| 100|  5|10
```

Now here the 45 are duplicates and I want to eliminate the entire first row. Even though the other values are different they mean nothing so they must be deleted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$A, $A1)>1
```

[image: 0]

---

for 2nd+ occurance you can do:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1, $A1)>1
```

[image: 0]

Comment: this command is to highlight duplicates correct? the formula that I have up there does that as well, I was just wondering if there is a command that highlights the row of the duplicate.

Comment: I used the code that you mention but only the first cell of the duplicate gets highlighted. Is there anyway to get the whole row of that highlighted portion?

Comment: pls doublecheck with the answer

Comment: Yeah sorry about that my workplace browser doesn't show images. Thanks! the code does work but i'm having trouble since it's highlighting (n+1) of the duplicate. In other words the duplicate is let's say (311, but it's highlighting 312.)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Of the whole entire excel sheet?

Comment: on your picture it's still highlighting the next cell. 31130 is a duplicate but it doesn't highlight it, it will highlight the next one. Also 39016, that one is the duplicate but it highlights 39017 (green) which is not a duplicate.

Comment: Hey just to update you. I cleared the formatting for the whole sheet and used the first command you gave me and everything is in order. Thank you for helping me out!